# Is it possible to configure SSRS web server to cache datasets on "session" level?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to configure SSRS web server to cache datasets on "session" level?

I mean the browsing through standard SSRS web front-end, but I'm not sure that it supports sessions ..

(P.S. the real problem is that the user action "going deeper into group" is too slow - dataset is re-queried for each 'clicking on plus').

Comment: Does "standard SSRS web front-end" mean Report Manager? What version?

Comment: Yes, standard for SQL SERVER 2012 web-based report access and management application that known as 'Reoprt Manager' in msdn.  It doesn't have any "abot.." window so I can't specify it's 'official' name and 'official' version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set Cache options for this report.

From the Folder view, click on the Open Menu button next to the report and choose Manage, then Processing.  Choose the "Cache a temporary copy ..." option that best suits your scenario.

Personally I dont like the "clicking on plus" UI.  You may find that the HTML rendering effort is also slow once the dataset is cached.

Instead I prefer to set Bookmarks which result in a Report Map (hyperlinks).  The UI is cleaner and faster.

Comment: Recommendation to use hyperlinks is an answer. Generic cache - is not an answer, since it doesn't enable comfortably with 'plus ui' requests (still too long, and I think still requesting the dataset from DB).